# How to format the output of tree in linux so the colour scheme still applies?

Tags: linux, tree

How can I format the output of a tree command so that the formatting of ls, e.g. highlighting and colour scheme of directories and certain file types applies to the output?
The problem is when I restrict the depth of tree to say 2, if there are any directories in the final level, there is not a noticeable difference between dirs and files. So someway to easily distinguish between the two, whilst displaying both files and dirs would be great. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `tree -C`. And `man tree`.

Comment: Thanks @rom1v . Is there a way to set colourisation as default for tree without using flags?

Comment: `man tree` says: _which is colorized ala dircolors if the `LS_COLORS` environment variable is set and output is to tty_

Comment: `alias tree="tree -C"` or set `LS_COLORS` as you want.

Comment: Just add this `export CLICOLOR=1` and it will use default colors if `LS_COLORS` is unset.

Comment: But how should we set `LS_COLORS`? I set it like `LS_COLORS=red` but it doesn't work in this way.

Answer (score 23):

```
tree -C
```

> -C
>
> Turn colorization on always, using built-in color defaults if the `LS_COLORS` environment variable is not set. Useful to colorize output to a pipe.

see [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) page.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use tree with Level 2, so this my favorite alias:

```
tre='tree -CL 2'
```

[image]